# How to Compare date & time & get the difference then set it as seconds in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, seconds

How can I compare the two date like:

```
Event Date: May 25, 2015 02:00:00
```

and the second date will be the Client date like ex: `May 20, 2015 05:00:00`
What was my goal to achieve is to get the difference of it the convert it to seconds. How can I get this done, im new in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var t1 = new Date(2015, 05, 25, 2, 0, 0, 0)
var t2 = new Date(2015, 05, 20, 5, 0, 0, 0) 

var diff = t1.getTime() - t2.getTime()

var secondsFromT1ToT2 = diff / 1000;
var secondsBetweenDates = Math.abs(secondsFromT1ToT2);

console.log(secondsBetweenDates)
# 421200
```